# Static Object of Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I think I am going the wrong way around this issue I have. Currently I access the user role name by @UserRole.CurrentRole. This works fine until another login changes their role then all people who are logged in, their UserRole.CurrentRole is whoever has changed theirs last.

I have some functionality that sets UserRole.CurrentRole = "Learner"; or UserRole.CurrentRole = "Administrator"; based on if a user is within that role.

```
public static class UserRole
{
    private static String _CurrentRole;

    public static String CurrentRole
    {
        get
        {
            return _CurrentRole;
        }
        set
        {
            _CurrentRole = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not want to use a `static` class for user info in ASP.NET.  `static` classes are scoped by AppPool (roughly), so users using the site will be constantly reading (and overwriting) the same static object.  Use a non-static object and put it in the `Session`.

Comment: Thank you. Will do it that way.